# Call ajax in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

When i click on Call my webservice button its id="click-me-web-service" then the ajax request send and call my file hit-web-service.php but i found error on this stage help me to solve it. Is my method correct to call the php file?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#click-me-web-service").click(function() {

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{$base_dir}modules/wrd_web_service/hit-web-service.php",
          data: { first_name: "Joh", last_name: "Sin", username: "johsin", email: "john12@gmail.com" },
          success: function() {
          
            console.log("Success.");
          
          }

        });

    })

});
```

Comment: whats the error your getting now?

Answer (score 1):

please be careful when using js codes inside smarty templates. The use braces `{}` inside tpl may conflict, when you want real braces in your js use `{literal}`

please modify your code as below

```
{literal}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#click-me-web-service").click(function() {

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{/literal}{$base_dir}{literal}modules/wrd_web_service/hit-web-service.php",
          data: { first_name: "Joh", last_name: "Sin", username: "johsin", email: "john12@gmail.com" },
          success: function() {

            console.log("Success.");

          }

        });

    })

});
{/literal}
```